# Interactive world map

Tags: javascript, maps

I'm looking for a javascript world map, much like Google Maps, that can be embedded into a webpage, and extended so I can plot my own points on it. The major catch is that the map needs to be completely usable without an internet connection (i.e., local intranet). It doesn't need to have the same level of detail as Google Maps, but should be able to have a little bit of zoom capabilities. Any ideas?

**Edit:** I'm not talking about a street map, more like an atlas map, preferably with terrain data. Sorry

Comment: Do you realize how much local data you're talking? A street map for a single city takes about 100 MB.

Comment: Any particular reason to choose Javascript if it should to be "usable without internet"?

Comment: How about a high resolution picture of the earth (1600x1200) in a scrolling div? Make the div 400x300. If you want to zoom in, scale picture dimensions appropriately.

Comment: What functionality would you expect offline? For example you could cache a small area of the Earth, and only have that available offline. Or of course you could cache the lowest level of detail for the whole world (and I do mean *really* low level of detail if you want to do that) and cache specific areas in higher detail. If you want the entire earth that's a lot of data. it turns out that the planet is quite big

Comment: @EDIT:: Ironically a streetmap is probably easier. terrain data is continuous wheras streets are vector data. So streets are a much smaller data format!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to investigate [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/), which is an open source web-based mapping engine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any engines off the top of my head, but there are several sources of map data that are free to use:

If you can utilize imagery without street data, [NASA's Blue Marble](http://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/Features/BlueMarble/) project is handy.  However, as mentioned by others, the data can be very large.

For street maps you could download the [whole planet database from OpenStreetMap](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm), but it's about 160GB uncompressed!

For topography, you could try [GLOBE](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/topo/globe.html).